# C# vsto add worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

All my code works but when I write to the cells in the new sheets, writes to the first Sheet1. The sheets are not created until the click event ends.

Is there another event I could fire after the click event to populated the new sheets created?

How can I work around this? Thanks...

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


namespace Prototype
{
    public partial class Ribbon1
    {
        private Excel.Application xlApp;
        private Workbook xlWorkBook;
        private Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        private dynamic excelSheet;
        private Range range;

        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e) { }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            xlApp = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            xlApp.Visible = true;
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Item[1];
            excelSheet = xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
            xlApp = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;

            xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add(After: xlWorkBook.Sheets[xlWorkBook.Sheets.Count]);
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Item[2];
            xlWorkSheet.Select();
            xlWorkSheet.Name = "Dashboard";

            xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add(After: xlWorkBook.Sheets[xlWorkBook.Sheets.Count]);
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Item[3];
            xlWorkSheet.Select();
            xlWorkSheet.Name = "Dashboard2";

            xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(After: xlWorkBook.Sheets[xlWorkBook.Sheets.Count]);
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Item[4];
            xlWorkSheet.Select();
            xlWorkSheet.Name = "Dashboard3";

            xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Dashboard"];
            xlWorkSheet.Select();
            range = excelSheet.Cells[1, 1];
            range.Value2 = "Test";

            xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Dashboard2"];
            xlWorkSheet.Select();
            range = excelSheet.Cells[1, 1];
            range.Value2 = "Test";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining the range based on `excelSheet` which you defined as the Active sheet before you created the new one. Just because you select the `xlWorkSheet` doesn't mean that `excelSheet` changed value. Your code should be

```
xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Dashboard"];
range = xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
range.Value2 = "Test";

xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Dashboard2"];
range = xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
range.Value2 = "Test";
```

Comment: Also, it would be better if you define different variables for each sheet, instead of reusing variables. That way the code would look cleanier